# File download in Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I habe a Vaadin 23 app running on a wildfly server. I want to add a button which then start to download a file which is located under the web-inf directory. I only found this [blog article](https://vaadin.com/blog/uploads-and-downloads-inputs-and-outputs) which seems to be outdated.

Which is the best (preferred) way to achieve this?

Thanks and kind regards
Matt

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to get the file as resource and set it to `Anchor`. Then you can have a `Button` which programmatically clicks the `Anchor`.

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
anchor.setText("Download");
anchor.getElement().getStyle().set("display", "none");
anchor.getElement().setAttribute("download", true);

anchor.setHref(resource);
Button button = new Button("Download");
button.addClickListener(event -> {
    anchor.getElement().callJsFunction("click");
});
add(anchor, button);
```

There is also an [add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper) in Vaadin's Directory that packages the above process.

Note, if you want to have the Download button in the Dialog, make sure that Anchor is not in the Dialog, see another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163889/streamresource-sometimes-resource-not-found-when-clicking-download-button-in-a-c).

You can find also more complete download example [here](https://gist.github.com/TatuLund/0a0e7bdc1d182394c99fe2adfa3e7c6e).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I came up with this method:

```
private Button createDownloadButton(String fileName) {
    Icon icon = VaadinIcon.FILE_TABLE.create();
    icon.setColor("green");
    Button downloadButton = new Button(fileName, icon);
    downloadButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
    downloadButton.setDisableOnClick(true);
    downloadButton.addClickListener(event -> {
        InputStream inputStream = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext()
                .getResourceAsStream(UiFactory.DOWNLOAD_PATH + fileName);
        ReadableByteChannel readChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
        Path downloadPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), fileName);
        FileChannel writeChannel = null;
        
        try(FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath.toFile())) {
            writeChannel = fileOS.getChannel();
            writeChannel.transferFrom(readChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            String message = String.format("Successfully transferred file to %s.", downloadPath.toString());
            showStatusMessage(message, null, MessageStatus.SUCCESS);
            downloadButton.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            // handle IO exceptions
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writeChannel != null){
                    writeChannel.close();
                }
                readChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle IO exceptions
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem here is that there is no dialog to ask the user where to store the file. So the JS solution is pretty smart here.